# Xdebug - change var_dump nesting level

Tags: php, xdebug

Hello i enabled the Xdebug extension, but when i dump a long array(like 1000 positions) the xdebug supress the values... is it possible to turn off the supression, not the Xdebug plugin...

here an example to you guys..

```
object(stdClass)[213]
  public 'OrderGetByStatusResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[214]
      public 'OrderDTO' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[215]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[230]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[266]
              ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to change your `Xdebug` settings, take a look at the http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings page:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_children
xdebug.var_display_max_data
xdebug.var_display_max_depth
```

Add settings to your `php.ini` or `xdebug.ini`. For your case is `xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1` to have maximum nesting level.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the quick copy and paste answer for those using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server

```
sudo vi /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

# paste the following to the file
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
```

Save and exit.

```
# for apache2 server
sudo service apache2 restart

# for nginx
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Would propose to adjust those settings to needs, not set all to MAX. So much data can crash browser for example.